# Moving files into directory in foreach loop?

Tags: php, move

i've no idea how to do that and need your help!

i have an array of filenames called $bundle. (file_one.jpg, file_two.pdf, file_three.etc)
and i have the name of the folder stored in $folder. (my_directory)

i now would like to move all the files stored in $bundle to move to the directory $folder.

how can i do that?

```
    //print count($bundle); //(file_one.jpg, file_two.pdf, file_three.jpg)
    $folder = $folder = PATH . '/' . my_directory;
 foreach ($bundle as $value) {

  //rename(PATH.'/'.$value, $folder . '/' . $value);

 }
```

just so it's not confusing: PATH just stores the local file-path im using for my project. in my case it's just the folder i'm working in-so it's "files".

i have no idea which method i have to use for this and how i could solve that!

thank you for your help!

Comment: you need to use rename like in your example , what you get in this example

Comment: set a bit more detail , if possible add some more code to be exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code given by you should work with minor changes:

```
$folder = PATH . '/' . 'my_directory'; // enclose my_directory in quotes.
foreach ($bundle as $value) {
        $old = PATH.'/'.$value, $folder;
        $new = $folder . '/' . $value;
        if(rename($old,$new) !== false) {
                // renamed $old to $new
        }else{
                // rename failed.
        }
}
```

Comment: thank you works fine, except is there an easy way to do the same with directories?

imagine the $bundle Array contains not only files but directories as well. (file_one.jpg, directory1, file_two.pdf, another-directory)
i'm checking for a folder with $ext = pathinfo($value, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); if ($ext == '') { its a folder!!!

i just need a function or a method which let's me move complete directories with all it's contents!?

Comment: @mathi just because a file doesnt have an extension doesnt mean it's a folder. Use `is_dir` to check if a directory is a directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
$folder = PATH . '/' . $folder;
foreach ($bundle as $value) {
        $old = PATH.'/'.$value;
        $new = $folder . '/' . $value;
        if(rename($old,$new) !== false) {
                // renamed $old to $new
        }else{
                // rename failed.
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should work:

```
function bulkMove($src, $dest) {
    foreach(new GlobIterator($src) as $fileObject) {
        if($fileObject->isFile()) {
            rename(
                $fileObject->getPathname(),
                rtrim($dest, '\\/') . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $fileObject->getBasename()
            );
        }
    }
}
bulkMove('/path/to/folder/*', '/path/to/new/folder');
```

Could add some checks to see if the destination folder is writable. If you dont need wildcard matching, change the `GlobIterator` to `DirectoryIterator`. That would also eliminate the need for PHP5.3